# How does the transistor in an op-amp log amplifier work?

Tags: operational-amplifier

In the figure, you could connect the transistor Q1 as a diode by shorting its collector with its base, but instead it is done by keeping both base and collector at ground.

The text says that if it were connected the other way (by shorting collector and base) then the base current would have caused an error (base current error.)

- What type of error is the author talking about?
- Why and how does the error manifest?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you short collector to base and use it as a diode between the opamp output and the inverting input then any base current has to flow from the input signal causing an error, especially at low currents where the HFE drops off.

In the arrangement shown the base current flows to ground and so the current flowing into the input is slightly less. This could cause an error of a few % at low currents.

The configuration shown can provide a logarithmic function over about 9 decades, a diode-connected version can work for 5-6 decades.

Here is some good information that has a brief mention of both types  [Log Amplifiers](https://web.archive.org/web/20180127204221/http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/ypanarin/Lecture%20Notes/DT021-4/6LogAntiLogAmplifiers.pdf)

Comment: What kind of changes can this error brings into the output voltage...?

Comment: A few % of the input current would go into the base and cause that percentage of error.

Comment: For temparature compensation of the circuit Q2 is involved because involving will make the circuit output independent of the reverse leakage currents which are temparature dependent for temparature compensation both the transistor Vbe should be equal and opposite and the net difference of both voltages should be equal to output voltage
When diodes are involved in compensation the equations are
Vo=[25mV*ln(Iref/Is2)] - [25mV*ln(I1/Is1)] 
=25mV*ln(Iref/I1)

Is diode leakage current
I1 diode current 
Io Iref

What are the equations when transistor are involved ??
I m not sure of the equations...

Comment: why does the transistor-as-diode version of the log amp provide a wider range (9 decades) than the diode version (5-6 decades)? [edit: your link to the document at the end of the post is not working]